# How to archive binary data

Tags: python, zip, pickle, archive

Use `zipfile` to archive `data` dictionary:

```
import os, sys, cPickle, zipfile 
data = {1: 'one'}
pfile = r'c:\temp\myPickle.p'
cPickle.dump( data, open( pfile, "wb" ))

zfilename = r'c:\temp\myArchive.zip'
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zfilename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zfile.write(pfile, os.path.basename(pfile))
zfile.close()
```

The approach results two files on a local drive: one is pickle and another is zip.
To get pickled `data` zip file needs to be un-archived:

```
fh = open(zfilename, 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
for each in z.namelist():
    z.extract(each, r'c:\temp')
fh.close()
```

How to simplify the process?

Comment: [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open), [ZipFile.read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read), [ZipFile.writestr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr)

Comment: from some quick googling i found the functions you probably need: `preserved = pickle.dumps(data)` dumps generates a string. zipfile has .writestr() for turning strings into zip. this way only one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gzip` instead. It compresses the file as you write it so there is no need for intermediate files.

```
# (python 2) import cPickle as pickle
import pickle
import gzip

data = {1: 'one'}

pfile = r'test.pkl.gz'
pickle.dump(data, gzip.open(pfile, "w"), pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
print pickle.load(gzip.open(pfile))
```